# OpenCV imread 8BPP PNG image error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to read an 8BPP PNG image using imread() in OpenCV and copy it into a larger matrix. This is the code:

```
Mat subimage = imread((directory + file).toStdString(), IMREAD_COLOR);
subimage.copyTo(whole(Rect(rect.left(), rect.top(),
                                       rect.width(), rect.height())));
```

I have tried other flags like IMREAD_ANYCOLOR, IMREAD_ANYDEPTH, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and IMREAD_UNCHANGED. None of them seem to work (subimage remains empty).

I am getting the folowing error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize()) in cv::_OutputArray::release, file ..\..\..\sources\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1619`

Comment: No separator between `directory` and `file`? No checking if image was loaded?

Comment: I could add the check..Currently, I have a print statement that prints out the number of rows and columns of subimage. The dimensions of rect is correct. Also, the directory variable ends with a separator..I add the seperator in a seperate part of the code. I printed that out as well and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the error. However, it has nothing to do with imread. I am downloading the images and was trying to read them before the download is complete.